# When I remove the scanf line from this code then I get the correct ouput as "hello" but on using scanf I get the output as "bye".... Why so?

Tags: c

This code produces correct output without scanf line. The function returns different value on using scanf. Why so??

```
 int main()
 {
 int choice;
 scanf("%d",&choice);
 bool a=admi_login();
 if(a==true)
    printf("\n hello");
 else
    printf("Bye");
 }   
bool admi_login()
{
printf("Enter the Admin Password\n");
char pw[100];
int i;
for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
{
    pw[i]=getch();
    if(pw[i]=='\r')
        break;
    printf("*");
}
char pw1[100]="admin\r";
if((strcmp(pw,pw1))==0)
  return true;
else
 return false;}
```

Comment: Start a debugger and step through your code line by line.

Comment: "I changed the code, and the code's output changed! Why?"

Comment: Hint: what is `pw[i]` the first time `pw[i]=getch();` occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scanf will leave the input stream at the first whitespace it encounters. Your login function stops at the first whitespace, so it will never read the rest of the password.